# MediaTypeFormatter serialize enum string values in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, enums

Consider this code:

```
public Gender Get()
{
    return Gender.Female;
}
public enum Gender
{
   Male,
   Female
}
```

This code is a Web API controller that returns `Gender` enum. When we use `XmlTypeFormatter` and call the method, it returns `Male` or `Female`. But when we use `JsonTypeFormatter` we get the value of enum, such as 1.

Why is it so?! and how can we get `Female` or `Male` from `JsonTypeFormatter`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your application start:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

protected void Application_Start()
{
   SerializeSettings(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

}

void SerializeSettings(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   JsonSerializerSettings jsonSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings();
   jsonSetting.Converters.Add(new Converters.StringEnumConverter());
   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jsonSetting;
}
```

Comment: I had to change a setting for the `StringEnumConverter` and set its property `AllowIntegerValues = false`

Answer (score 26):

Since the settings object should already be there, here's a simplified version of hutchonoid's code:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
```